# Not able to add todos to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to write the code for my todo app in React.

I can't seem to add a new todo to my database with the handleSubmit function. However, when I use Postman, a todo gets added, but for some sort of reason it doesn't work when I try entering a todo in the input field on my app and submit it. Anyone that can see what's wrong?

---

**Todo.js component - FRONT-END**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Todo.css'  
import Todoitem from '../components/Todoitem'
import axios from 'axios'
import qs from "qs"
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"

class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            title:"",
            todos:[]
        }
        this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/todo`,
            withCredentials: true
        })
            .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let todolist = response.data;
            this.setState({todos:todolist})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("You've made an error when getting the todos charles: ",error)
        })
    }

    handleChange(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        let name = event.target.name
        let value = event.target.value
        this.setState({
            [name]:value
        })
        console.log(this.state.title)
    }

    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        if (!this.state.title) {
            debugger
        }  
        axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/todo`,
            data: qs.stringify({title: this.state.title}),
            headers: {"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response)
        })
    }

    handleDelete(todoId){
        axios
        .delete(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/todo/${todoId}`)
        .then(response => {
            const remainingTodos = this.state.todos.filter(element => element._id !== todoId)
            this.setState({
                todos: remainingTodos
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DefaultLayout>
                <h1>To-do things for this app</h1>
                <h2 className="todotitle">Add your to-do here, Charles!</h2>
                <form className="todocontainer" onClick={this.handleSubmit}> 
                    <div className="inputbuttonandfield">    
                        <div className="inputcontainer">
                            <form className="captionpart">
                                <label className="captionlabel" htmlFor="title">Add to-do:</label><br></br>
                                <input className="captionform" type="text" name="title" value={this.state.title} placeholder="Type your to-do here!" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <button className="shootbutton">Add!</button>
                    </div>
                </form> 

                {
                    this.state.todos.map(element=> (
                     <div className="todosoverviewlister">
                        <Todoitem key={element._id} id={element._id} title={element.title} />

                        <button className="tododelete" onClick={()=> this.handleDelete(element._id)}>Delete</button>
                     </div>
                    ))
                }

                </DefaultLayout>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Todo
```

---

**Todo - model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const todoSchema = new Schema({
    title: String
})

const Todo = mongoose.model("todos",todoSchema)

module.exports = Todo
```

---

**INDEX.js - backend**

```
//add to-do
router.post("/todo", (req,res) => {
  Todo
  .create({
    title: req.body.title
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("Charles the post todo is working")
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Charles the post todo is NOT working")
    res.json(error)
  })
})

//request todos
router.get("/todo", (req,res) => {
  Todo
  .find()
  .then(response => {
    res.json(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    res.json(error)
  })
})
```

Comment: have you checked if there is any error message on the console?

Comment: When you send from postman are you sending as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or as JSON? Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network also to see if what you send is as expected, what status is etc

Comment: Also do check the network tab if the request shows 200 status code or failure.

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to inspect the raw requests sent and compare between Postman's and your browser's requests. Find the difference.

Comment: @Mario: I have this error in the console: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. but don't think this has something to do with it...

Comment: @charlietfl: sending it as application/x-www-form-urlencoded , would you mind having another quick look? I think the error is in the   data: qs.stringify({ title: this.state.title })

Comment: @CherryDT: thanks I tried Fiddle but could find the issue. I think the error is in the data: qs.stringify({ title: this.state.title })

Comment: @charlesbxl: You said you didn't find the issue, but what differences in the requests did you find then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your HTTP request is never sent because your `handleSubmit` method never runs. And this happens due to the fact that `onSubmit` event does not exist on a `<div>` element.

`onSubmit` event is only applicable to `<form>` elements. In order to fire this event (and therefore run your handler method) you have to add this event handling to the `<form>` element and make sure that your "Add" button is of `type="submit"`

Please, try the code below:

```
...
<!-- here is your form with onSubmit event -->
<form className="todocontainer" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <div className="inputbuttonandfield">
    <div className="inputcontainer">
      <div className="captionpart" >
        <label className="captionlabel" htmlFor="title">
          Add to-do:
        </label>
        <br></br>
        <input
          className="captionform"
          type="text"
          name="title"
          value={this.state.title}
          placeholder="Type your to-do here!"
          onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
        ></input>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- this is your old button with type submit -->
    <button type="submit" className="shootbutton">Add!</button>
  </div>
</form>
...
```

You can also go with a good old `onClick` event like this

```
...
<div>
  <!-- this is your old button handles the onClick event -->
  <button className="shootbutton" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Add!</button> 
</div>
...
```

Comment: this is great man thanks! it works now to add a todo! However, everytime I add a todo (writing a todo in the input field and pushing submit button), 2 todos get added. 1 with the text I typed in the input field and another with an empty string "". Any idea why?

Comment: Please, make sure that you are using ONLY one solution: onSubmit OR onClick. They cannot be used at the same time. If that is not the case and you are using onSubmit only then try to debug: put an if statement like this in the `handleSubmit`: `if (!this.state.title) debugger;` and explore the call stack to see where it comes from. Btw if you find my answers useful, please, mark it as "Accepted"

Comment: hey man thanks a lot for your support, really appreciate it! I have editied my code in the question to the latest version. I added the debugger but can't seem to trigger it...any chance you could have another look at why might be causing it?

Comment: Double request is caused by this wrong line `<form className="todocontainer" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>`. Change it to `<form className="todocontainer" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>` and it should work

Comment: great it works now, thanks man! another small problem I'm having here is that I need to refresh the page after pushing the add button to see the new list. I assume this is because I use componentDidMount and this updates only at page refresh. Any idea how I can do this at page refresh (componentDidUpdate) AND at state change ?

Comment: I have answered your question and did not get it accepted which is not fair. Please, mark my answer as Accepted and create a new question. Then i will answer it

Comment: sure man! Could you please let me know if you have an answer to my new question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62396027/updating-a-page-at-refresh-and-change-of-state?noredirect=1#comment110353507_62396027